# How to execute MySQL commands in file from the host to container running MySQL server using Powershell?

Tags: mysql, docker, powershell

These are similar but not exactly the same

[How to execute MySQL command from the host to container running MySQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389458/how-to-execute-mysql-command-from-the-host-to-container-running-mysql-server)

[How to execute mysqldump command from the host machine to a mysql docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63740465/how-to-execute-mysqldump-command-from-the-host-machine-to-a-mysql-docker-contain)

This command works pretty in Git Bash even on Windows:

```
docker exec -i some_docker_container mysql -uroot -psome_password mydb<tables.sql
```

Same command on Powershell says:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'mydb<tables.sql'
```

How to pass tables.sql file as parameter?
(it contains some create tables statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command that works in Git Bash is using input redirection. That [doesn't work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1) in Powershell, as `<` is reserved for future use. Since Powershell doesn't parse `<` as redirection, it passes string literal `mydb<tables.sql` as the database name. Thus, the error message.

To execute the script file, use [-e "source script.sql"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/batch-mode.html) for invoking mysql client in batch mode processing.