# How to write a bash script to interact with a mysql database inside a docker container

Tags: bash, docker, prestashop

I have a PrestaShop database running in a docker container that I intend to [back up](https://github.com/kommetio/bashutils/tree/main/docker-volume-backup). The thing is, I need to put the e-commerce store into maintenance mode before I run it. Ideally, I intended to run the script on a remote machine - getting it to login via ssh and then interact with the container (via the script) but it seems I may (first) need to log in via ssh then run the script on the server? (as it starts a new shell etc).

These are the parts of the script that I have so far, but I'm just not sure how to put them together to string commands once inside mysql:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Log in to docker@debVM server via SSH
ssh docker@debVM

# Run the following Docker Container
docker exec -it ps1-7-mariadb-1 /bin/bash

# Login to the database bitnami_prestashop 
mysql -u bn_prestashop -pbitnamiUSER bitnami_prestashop

# Run update - store into maintenance mode
UPDATE ps_configuration SET value='0' WHERE name='PS_SHOP_ENABLE'; 

#Exit the mysql and docker exec
Exit 

#run the backup-volumes-container.sh script
echo running the backup-volumes-container.sh script
cd
cd scripts/
./backup-volumes-container.sh ps1-7-mariadb-1 
./backup-volumes-container.sh ps1-7-prestashop-1
echo Backup-volumes complete
```

Hope someone can help - thanks!

Comment: No need to shell into the Docker container, just run the commands from your script on the host: `docker exec -i ps1-7-mariadb-1 mysql -u... -p... bitnami_prestashop -e "UPDATE ps_configuration SET value='0' WHERE name='PS_SHOP_ENABLE';"` There are examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389458/how-to-execute-mysql-command-from-the-host-to-container-running-mysql-server To avoid passing password on the command line (which exposes it to everyone on the machine), you can put it into a config file, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22933056/6089612

Comment: its only me on the machine - will that still be a security problem? ...I will def look at the config method. Either way, the command works. Thanks for your help. Really great!

Answer (score 1):

A shell script is a sequence of shell commands, which can be a different thing from what you're typing in the terminal.  Your script runs `ssh`; then when that completes, it (locally) runs `docker exec`; then when that completes, it (locally, outside a container) runs `mysql`; and so on.  You can in principle provide an input to a command using pipe syntax, but this gets complicated as you step down into several layers.

Some commands have a way to provide their inner command as a command-line argument.  For example, `mysql -e 'SELECT ...'` will run a single SQL call, or `docker exec container-name command arg1` will run a single command.

But: I think you can run this completely locally, without any nested commands or `docker exec` at all.

The one bit of setup you do need to do is to make the database accessible from outside a container.  When you start the container, make sure you publish a port

```bash
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:12345:3306 ... mysql
```

If you use Compose, its `ports:` has the same syntax.  If you remove the `127.0.0.1` at the front, the container will be fully network-accessible, which I'm guessing you don't want.  The `12345` can be any port number not otherwise in use, but the last number must be `3306` to match the standard database port.

Having done this, on the target system, you can now access the database on host `127.0.0.1` port `12345` directly from the host, without using Docker tools.  (Remember that IP address is very context-specific, and it means something different on the local system, the remote system, and in the container.)

You can similarly use `ssh` to set up a port forward:

```bash
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:23456:127.0.0.1:12345 -f -N docker@debVM
```

Again, `23456` is any otherwise-unused local port, and `12345` matches `12345` from above.  Now port `23456` on the local system forwards to port `12345` in the remote system, which forwards to port `3306` in the container.

With this setup, you can now directly run `mysql` locally

```bash
mysql \
  -h 127.0.0.1 -p 23456 \
  -u bn_prestashop -pbitnamiUSER \
  -e "UPDATE ps_configuration SET value='0' WHERE name='PS_SHOP_ENABLE';" \
  bitnami_prestashop
```

and similarly run your backup script locally, pointing at the port-forwarded database connection.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and detailed explanation. Im going to try this out. I really appreciate your help! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to run a command on the OS within your docker container, check out [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/). You can install a mysql client in the dockerfile for your container, and then just use it via docker exec like you would on a host machine.

If you need to get data out of the container, you can map a log file or something to your container as a file volume and have your container write output to that file.

There's an example of what I'm talking about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389458/how-to-execute-mysql-command-from-the-host-to-container-running-mysql-server).

Comment: The question already uses `docker exec`.